# How to read password in the nodes when PageNode has multiple Password collector as a input

Tags: openam, forgerock

I am creating an authentication tree in openam-6.5.2 and I need to use `PageNode` in ForgeRock with multiple `Password Collector node` in it. How can I read both the password in next node. Password are stored in transient state but I am able to retrieve only one of them.

Is there anyway to read both the passwords at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

In the forgerock AM doc they state:

```
The Password Collector authentication node prompts the user to enter their password. 
The captured password is transient, persisting only until the authentication flow 
reaches the next node requiring user interaction.
```

So you cant store two password in the process, but you can put store the first password value in the userprofile in LDAP, ( by using custom attributs tmp, or password_tmp), you can do this via a custom node that will use LDAP API to send the update attributs request.

You can also store the first password in the session by using the default Set Session Properties Node, beware that in this case the password should be encrypted or hashed, if the session is client side.

Comment: there is no requirement to store password in LDAP as password are yubikey and OTPs.

Comment: then you have to store it in the user session, and delete it later for security reasons